# Trick Or Treat - What gives with the soundtrack?

Tags: soundtrack, trick-or-treat

Anyone know why [Trick Or Treat (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092112/) (which stars Gene Simmons and Ozzy Osbourne) didn't have a single track by either artist on the soundtrack?  And why they chose **Fastway** (of all bands) to do the majority of it?  I'm fairly confident that had a lot to do with its financial failure, but I'm just curious if anyone knows what De Laurentiis was thinking by doing that?  I don't ever recall them being overly popular or "up-and-coming".

Answer (score 2):

[Fastway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastway_%28band%29), the band, recorded their debut album, also named [Fastway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastway_%28album%29), in the year 1983. According to wikipedia's sources, the debut album was a critical and commercial success.

> After critical and commercial success, the band toured to promote the
>   album (with one-time Fixx bassist Alfie Agius as their session bass
>   player). The band then recruited Charlie McCracken, formerly of Taste,
>   as "permanent" bassist, and **released another success in the form of
>   All Fired Up the following year.** After the hardships of touring,
>   Shirley and McCracken subsequently left.After critical and commercial
>   success, the band toured to promote the album

So they could have been seen as an *'up and coming'* band during 1986.
That could've been the reason why they were approached for the movie.

Secondly, in the same article on Wikipedia, they mention that

> Fastway was approached to make the soundtrack for the heavy metal
>   horror film, Trick or Treat. **The film flopped, but the soundtrack
>   re-established Fastway as a hard-hitting metal band. The soundtrack
>   was a moderate success, and stayed on the Billboard Top 200 chart for
>   eleven months.**

So may be Fastway was not solely responsible for the movie's commercial failure.